# Link preload issues

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script, web-applications, preload

I am working on a simple dev in Google Apps Script. I also have html part. I can see in the browser console that there are issues related to link preload. Any recommendations or advisory on how to handle these errors? Details below:

[Chrome console screen with the preload issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxdEV.png)

My html head code:

```
<head>
  <base target="_top">
   <link rel="preconnect" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="preload" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css" as="style">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. This should show if you are above in a dialog/sidebar or and web app.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you preload your asset but don't use it, in order to load and use it add **onload** attribute to your link, or just use that asset like your third link by using **rel="stylesheet"** and remove **as** attribute

```
<head>
  <base target="_top">
   <link rel="preconnect" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="preload" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
</head>
```

Comment: `Add onload attribute to your link` - why is this important? Can you explain?

Comment: I can't paste a screen here in the comment, so please see a link showing how it looks after using the onload attribute. The errors still appear. I am not sure if I was specific enough. More details on the errors https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/0ayk78uOBDr9kyIwHhIv5kzw73qZePvOFrw-bAxwGzc1ev93gm5bK3emeOQV70B3pp9E4w_KrMIiNWykDx17o1BO8-sHprdALa1_szV1VD4x0_oxD13qgYskKJhcpHxfL4nyQeIYeQS2iqAHuLyhNSVim837UG7zlEaw1SKxa89b1Ho4P0uCmxjEvw

Comment: make sure that you clear the cache and reload the page,

Comment: I did exactly as suggested adding the proper attributes. In my case, It don't work. I am wondering if sth else isn't messing here, as I am writing in Google IDE, also using a bit of js and in dev mode. Your hint seems perfectly fine, but errors still occur. I will try to do additional checks and let here know if I managed to solve this issue. Thanks